# Why does SSIS now convert SQL DATEs to DT_WSTR?

Tags: ssis

I upgraded my SSIS 2008 packages to 2012.  Now suddenly they all want to treat the SQL Server DATE fields coming from data sources as DT_WSTRs instead of the DT_DBDATEs that they were in 2008....does anybody know why or how to stop it from doing this?

It's been forcing me to add data type conversions to convert the DT_WSTRs back into DB_DBDATEs for the sake of lookups and comparisons, and it's extremely annoying....

Comment: Same question I do. What should I do when Lookup also cast DATE to DT_WSTR. No way to cast here.

Comment: Now five years later and no one has an answer for this?? Better question in why is SSIS so terrible?